# how to preserve the orgianl backgroundColor when hovering?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

below is the code that works fine but the only problem i have is : its overriding the alternative row with `backgroundColor='white'` how can i have my orginal alternative color when onmouseout ?

```
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DEEEE9" Font-Size="8pt" />

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#C2D69B'");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what color exactly should be restored on `onmouseout`:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    string bgcolor = "white"
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
    {
       bgcolor = "#DEEEE9";
    }

    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#C2D69B'");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='" + bgcolor  + "'");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
}
```

Comment: why would you do this rather than use whats built in with style sheet functionality. Css classes even provide the functionality for it with the hover element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, why not just take out the "e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");" and set it to the color of the original alternate???

Comment: the highlight color would then stay and not revert back until another row is moused over. It shows 'selected' when it was really just a hover.

Answer (score 0):

instead of specifying a specific color, use the hover css attributes.
See:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MouseHoverUsingCSS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var color = "<%=System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor)%>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well with much less code.  Create a custom attribute in the mouseover before setting the backgroundColor and use it on the mouse out.  Works perfectly for alternating row colors.

```
row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.backgroundColor='#ffccff';";

row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;";
```